# MySQL for Excel connection

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql for Excel to edit table data on excel.
On connecting it replies:
"Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style password"

Any help please

Comment: I'd say google that error message for details

Comment: You'll find the duplicate this refers to